# What is the word for an unmarried female?

Tags: single-word-requests

An unmarried male is called a bachelor. Is there an English word for an unmarried female?

Comment: My first result from Google was [The free dictionary - unmarried woman](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/unmarried+woman), which lists synonyms. What did you find lacking in these definitions?

Comment: @MattЭллен - They are kinda lame? IMHO only the first of the three even comes close to a good answer, and it is a recent loan word from Spanish.

Comment: @T.E.D I was more dismayed about the lack of research shown in the question. I agree that the definitions in the link are below par. If nicholas shows us what he already knows by editing the question and putting some effort in, then I will gladly vote to reopen.

Comment: @Alenanno Strange that it has been closed as the inconclusive answers given so far have revealed that the question cannot be easily answered by a standard internet reference as has been stated below.

Comment: Bachelorette seems to be specifically American, spinster seems inappropriate as could be offensive and maiden is too general. I found the same problem with the synonyms on the net. Is there not some type of legal definition?

Answer (score 6):

> Bachelorette is an American English term for an unmarried woman. A
>   bachelorette may have once been in a marriage or pair bonding
>   relationship that produced children in her past. The term is derived
>   from the word bachelor.

[source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bachelorette)

Answer (score 4):

The word is "spinster", but it has completely different connotations.  "Bachelor" often implies "young, free and single" whereas "spinster" often is more "lonely, old, left-on-the-shelf".

Comment: This is the technically correct term. If it is not suitable, I suggest the OP explains the context for which he needs to know.

Comment: @Urbycoz I can't think of a contemporary context in which the word "spinster" *would* be suitable.

Comment: @onomatomaniak it's still used on marriage licenses (at least in the UK) if the women hasn't been married before.

Answer (score 1):

*Maiden* is also acceptable though somewhat ambiguous and antiquated. 

According to part of the [Online Etymology Dictionary](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=maiden&searchmode=none) entry on *maiden*:

> ... fem. variant of PIE base *maghu- "youngster of either sex, unmarried person" (cf. O.E. magu "child, son," Avestan magava- "unmarried," O.Ir. maug "slave").

Comment: The problem with this is that it is not applicable to a divorced or widowed single woman. Ultimately the word was intended to be reserved for virgins. Most dictionary definitions dance around this without actually coming out and saying it.

Comment: @T.E.D.: 'bachelor' is not used for divorced or widowed male either.

Comment: @Mitch - I've seen it used that way quite often.