# Female equivalent of "bachelor"?

Tags: single-word-requests, feminine

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the word for an unmarried female?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44227/what-is-the-word-for-an-unmarried-female)

[What is the word for an unmarried female?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44227/what-is-the-word-for-an-unmarried-female)
The above closed question is unanswered as *bachelorette* implies both unmarried and divorced/widowed. *Spinster* is for old women.

*Bachelor* is a never-married man.

Is there no such female equivalent of *bachelor*?

Comment: *Bachelor* does not mean *never* married. It just means single.

Comment: Why not just use "unmarried"?

Comment: After going through all the answers, I conclude there is no such female equivalent of bachelor!

Comment: @dnagirl But the Google dictionary says differently: “a man who is not and has never been married.”

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spinster isn't *for* old women, but it certainly would be more often used for that, and has a connotation of having failed to get a husband, rather than being happily unmarried.

*Bachelorette* is sometimes used solely for "unmarried" but does indeed sometimes include divorcées and widows. It's rarely used (was popular from about the 1930s through to the 1960s) and often considered patronising.

"Bachelor girl" is older than *bachelorette*, and generally only for never-married. It is now rare.

There isn't an exact equivalent, because the English language is influenced by thousands of years in which the status of different sexes both within and outside of marriage was not one of parity.

Comment: Yeah - somebody oughta sue the English Language.

Comment: Spinster is actually the legal term for an unmarried woman. The 'old' connotation has grown over the years.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Bet we could make it a class action: _ELU v. The English Language_.

Comment: *The Bachelorette* is the title of a current US "reality" television program. It is apparently back in fashion (of a sort).

Comment: "Bachelorette, you climb on rooftops and you - / Bachelorette, you can turn dust into champagne / you even remembered his name!". When I heard the title of the TV show @bib mentioned, I assumed a degree of irony, but haven't watched it myself (I prefer to watch drama to "reality", it's more realistic). I do note that in the US "a bachelorette party" is current for a party a bride has, normally with female-only friends, shortly before a wedding, and apparently because "hen party" is seen as less complimentary.

Comment: @bib, after all, who would watch a show called "Spinster"?  Oh what undeserved imagery goes with those two words - so close in meaning, so opposite in image! :-)

Comment: For that matter, who actually uses "bachelor" or anything like that in the modern world, anyway? I can't think of a single time I've cared a whit about anyone's martial status except if I was planning to marry them, planning to divorce them, paying a lawyer to change my own, or at least entertaining the thought of sleeping with them in the near future (the possible bachelor or bachelorette that is, not the lawyer; that would mess up the client-lawyer relationship).

Comment: @JonHanna - I would be concerned about someone's "martial status" <g> if I were a recruiting officer...

Comment: @MT_Head ah, typos like that are the best, aren't they?

Comment: @JonHanna - Yes.  Yes, they are.  =D

Answer (score 5):

An archaic term for this is *maid*. It is not very often used in that meaning any more though, and I would not recommend it. The online Merriam-Webster [defines it](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/maid) as:

> **maid** noun \ˈmād\
>
> Definition of MAID
>
> 1. an unmarried girl or woman, especially when young : virgin
> 2. a : maidservant
>
>    b : a woman or girl employed to do domestic work

*Maiden* is similar but that refers specifically to virginity.

Comment: I'm surprised that the senses are listed here in that order (as indeed they are at AHDEL and Collins). Collins _does_ at least add the _archaic_ qualifier to the entry for the _unmarried girl or woman_ polyseme. I'd have thought that (modern) relevance should determine order of senses.

Comment: Well, they've [probably been copying over the same entry since 1812 or so.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth but is it the sense of the word that's archaic, or the assumption that any respectable woman who wasn't married would still be a maid?

Comment: This probably explains why Robin Hood's camp was never all that tidy, despite the attentions of Maid Marian.

Comment: @MT_Head I think you misread her name. She was _made_ Marian, she was actually born Abigail.

Comment: and used this way in _Game of Thrones_.

Answer (score 2):

If you can draw some assumptions from the definition (below), ***"mistress"*** could be used. (Primarily, if a woman is the head of a household, she is likely - or traditionally - unmarried.)

> From [M-W-com]:[1](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mistress)
>
> 1: a woman who has power, authority, or ownership: as
>
> a: the female head of a household

Comment: Many royal mistresses have been married, either for convenience or propriety, and in general life mutual infidelities aren't that uncommon either - so if you meant *mistress* in the sense of "a woman having an affair with a married man", I don't think you can rely on it to signify her own marital status.

Comment: @MT_Head - thanks - I added a specific definition to back my answer.